# How to express all files/directories at the extra -exec option of `find` command?

Tags: command-line, find, regular-expression

I have a task to copy all files from multiple directories with special names to a target directory.

So I build this directory to test my command. The test directory tree looks like:

```
.
├── dir1
│   └── file1
└── test
```

My intended command to mv all files from dir1 to test is:

```
find . -type d -name "*dir*" -exec mv {}/* test \;
```

Then I got:

```
mv: rename ./dir1/* to test/*: No such file or directory
```

I guess this is because in that extra -exec expression, the command didn't treat the * as a wildcard.

So I did:

```
find . -type d -name "*dir*" -exec mv {}/file1 test \;
```

Which successfully moved file1 to test.

But the point is, I need to now the expression for all files so that I can accomplish this file transfer work.

How should I express that in the `find -exec` command group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mv "$dir_path"/* ...` will not only move files but everything in `"$dir_path"`. At least everything whose name does not start with a dot (hidden files). In bash you can change this with the option `dotglob`. But if the `*` expands nicely (matches everything but not too much for a command line) then you can use a shell for indirection:

```
find . -type d -name "*dir*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0"/* /path/to/test' {} \;
```

Comment: what does the end \; mean? Can them be omitted? I'm been have this doubt for a long time.

Comment: The `;` is the end of the `-exec` block (other tests / commands may follow). But as it is also a shell control operator it must be quoted for becoming part of the command line. You could use `';'` or `";"`.

Comment: Don't interpolate `{}` inside a shell script. That can't work unless you know that the file names are restricted to a “tame” set of characters. When you use `{}` inside a shell snippet, the file name is interpreted as a piece of shell syntax instead of being correctly treated as a string. Pass the file name as an argument instead. Cc @Zen

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ find -type d -name '*dir*' -exec sh -c '
  for d do
    for f in "$d"/*; do
      [ -f "$f" ] && mv -- "$f" /path/to/test
    done
  done
' sh {} +
```

Comment: Have you tried that? I guess `-exec` doesn't allow arguments between `{}` and `+`. You need `mv -t /path/to/test -- {} +`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Oh, my bad, It had another error that only one instance of `{}` is allowed. I changed my solution.

Comment: This is too complicate.

Comment: @Zen: Yes, the extra work to copy files only.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this as well . Considering the test directory is in the same directory with other directories ,

```
find . -mindepth 2  ! -name test -exec cp {} test \;
```

This will copy all individual files to the directory test ,  escaping the dir1 , dir2 etc.
Note that this will omit subdirectories itself and copies contents of them.
you can also test this by using ls command.

```
find . -mindepth 2  ! -name test -ls
```